# Python-eve: Create a custom webservice

Tags: python, web-services, eve

how do I create a Custom webservice using Python-eve?

If it was in Flask, I would only put the route decorator before the function and inside the function I could do whatever I wanted (call another service, run a python function, etc).

With Eve, I define de resources (domains) and it processes put, get, etc by itself using the database.

Should I just decorate a function like I would do with Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also register a Blueprint like you would do with any other Flask application. That's what [**Eve-Docs**](https://github.com/charlesflynn/eve-docs) is doing. You might want to check it out.

Eve *is* Flask (in fact, it is a subclass of it) so, in general, whatever works with Flask works with Eve too.

Comment: If I wanted to make some validations or create some fields before inserting a value to the DB, should I/can I inherit a class from Eve?

Comment: Another one is, as I am a pure SQL guy, how could I create my custom insert, delete, etc without relying on SQL Alchemy? Should I create a DataLayer? Sorry for the amount of questions, but I am trying to create the architecture in my head. I want to use all the nice functionalities of Eve (Easy apis, security, documentation, limit use) but I want to use other DBs and now exactly what is done on the DB side.

Comment: as these are unrelated to the current question please open new questions on SO as needed and I'll do my best to help out :)